# Im able to perform put and get status_code 200. but im really confused because it isn't sending out email to recipient to perform agree consent

Tags: docusignapi

Im soo confused now. before I was getting error 401 and 500 when i try to get and post to elastic template. now I get 200 status code. So i expect for an email to be sent out to recipient, but it isn't the api logs say that a request went through and there were no errors, and yet recipient receives no email.

Even when i use the test feature for the elastic template, it says it sent an email to recipient but recipient never recieves it.

SO maybe its a set up issue or I messed something up because it was working at the very beginning but now even the test template feature is not sending the email.

Answer (score 1):

An elastic template is meant to be viewed in an iframe within your application (commonly used for your application to show your clients terms for using your application). This is described [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/click101/concepts/). It is expected that an email will not go out for Elastic Templates. If you are looking for an agreement to be signed, you would be interested in sending an envelope - examples for which are available [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/#requesting-a-signature)

Comment: Issue not resolved 
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiy17KY0_2CAxXMAHkGHaoFAZAQFnoECBAQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.docusign.com%2Fdocs%2Fclick-api%2Fclick101%2Fmanaging-elastic-templates%2F%23%3A~%3Atext%3DYou%2520can%2520also%2520send%2520an%2Cand%2520emailing%2520it%2520to%2520them.&usg=AOvVaw0pNY2p0Uce2ayAWKBPc7aq&opi=89978449 
this link says it can be done. at the very beginning of the set up, when I tested the template using the test feature, it sent an email to me.